# What do I need this Laravel IDE helper for?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I found this very popular package on github.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

I've seen this used in several projects I've worked in but I am not sure what the benefits exactly are of this package. If I understand correctly it generates a file in the root of your project with a "clone" of the Laravel Framework. This should help with autocompletion.

I don't see any clear examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using with PHPStorm it does suggest autocomplete for methods and properties for facade classes. For instance Mail and DB classes are facades, and when using them, you won't have all the suggestions and also the methods will be highlighted as non existent.

Comment: So it's best used for "dumber" IDE's than PhpStorm?

Comment: @Michael It is for PhpStorm as well ... as it does not have special support for Laravel facades (it does not know how those facade magic works as the whole magic happens dynamically at runtime). And file(s) generated by this package help IDE with code completion/analysis.

Comment: @LazyOne can you give me a clear example of this "facade magic" you're talking about. This would make it better to understand, thanks.

Comment: @Michael Any method where you use facade (`Mail`, `DB` etc). If you check actual corresponding facade classes you will not see those methods there; they will be in another class.

Comment: @Michael For example: `Mail::to($user)->send(...);` -- `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail` facade class does not have `to()` method; it actually comes from `\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer` class.

Comment: @LazyOne, Facades without Interfaces seems like a lot of work to break dependency requirements. The whole point of this pattern is to allow dropping in any `Mailer`, but if that `Mailer` doesn't have a `::to()` method, it's all for naught.